# Pydoc Uncaught Exception

Tags: python, exception, pydoc

I looked up sys in pydoc because a book I am reading recommended it to me, I came across last_type which was type of last uncaught exception, my question is what is an uncaught exception in pydoc/python and what is it used for?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48046494/edit) to include more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An uncaught exception is just every exception which has not been handled by an except-handler within a try-except statement and hence causes your script to stop.

If this happens the interpreter by default prints the type of the exception, an error message and a traceback.

So if you, for example try to `print(1/0)`, you'll get an exception with type
`ZeroDivisionError`, an error message "division by zero" and the last steps through your code which led to the exception (traceback).

```
print(1/0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programme\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-
packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-12-2fc232d1511a>", line 1, in <module>
    print(1/0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

An uncaught exception lets you know that something went wrong. You then have to remove the error source (maybe you actually wanted to write `print(1/10)`, or you have to catch and handle the exception, allowing your program to resume execution of code beneath the error source.

```
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as err:  # error is caught here
    pass # e.g just do nothing
    # print(type(err).__name__, flush=True)  # or do something, like print
                                             # error type

print("will be printed because exception before was caught")
```